# c++ destructor behaviour in xll Release/Debug builds

Tags: c++, destructor

Is there any difference in the way `MyObject` is destroyed in the two following functions?

```
void myFunc1(){
    MyObject obj;
    // do something with the object
}

void myFunc2(){
    {
      MyObject obj;
      // do something with the object
    }
    // do some irrelevant random stuff that is not taken out by the compiler, for example
    std::string test = "test";
    test.append("blah");
}
```

The (virtual) destructor of `MyObject` is something like

```
MyObject::~MyObject()
{
    revert();
}
```

where `revert` is a public (non virtual) member function.

I'm asking because I noticed that, when running a Release build using `myFunc1`, it appears that the `revert` method is not called on destruction (while it is in Debug mode). I could see that because the method is supposed to change the value of a pointer that I can access from somewhere else in the code. The same issue doesn't happen for `myFunc2`.

In both cases I used an xll build and called the functions from Excel.

Edit:
The `revert` method calls the `revert` method of a member object defined in a nested class, which is simply

```
NestedObject::revert()
{
    *myPtr = myBackup;
}
```

it appears that it is not called. However if I add a line like

```
NestedObject::revert()
{
    OutputDebugString("test");
    *myPtr = myBackup;
}
```

then all works correctly. So my impression is that this is something related to compiler's optimizations.

Comment: The destructor of `obj` should be called in both cases, so if `revert` is not working correctly we'd have to see that function to know why.

Comment: @Rama I did put a breakpoint inside the revert() method. It is never reached in Release mode, while it is always reached in Debug mode. But I don't know if that's relevant since the debugger in Release mode is not super reliable...

Comment: @splinter123: have you tried launching Excel from inside windbg? `bp myxll!MyObject::~MyObject` should trap it. I find windbg better for release mode debugging.